# Как скрыть элемент на странице при прокрутке страницы вверх с помощью jQuery Waypoints?

Tags: jquery

Осваиваю плагин jQuert Waypoints.Имеется код:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="fixed-menu">
    <nav class="services">
        <ul class="">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

```
    $('.wrapper')
    .waypoint(function(dir){            
        $('.fixed-menu').css('display','block');
    }, {offset: '45%'});
```

Всё работает как нужно - элемент появляется, когда докручиваешь до блока wrapper. Но как сделать так, чтобы он исчезал при прокрутке вверх?

Знаю что нужно использовать отрицательный offset и проверку if(dir == "top"){}, но никакое шаманство с этими свойствами не срабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне себе работает манипуляция с *direction* (в работе: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/bj13e8m8/1/)**)

```
$('.wrapper')
    .waypoint(function(dir){ 
    if (dir=='down')  {
        $('.fixed-menu').show();
    }else {
         $('.fixed-menu').hide();   
    }
 }, {offset: '45%'});
```